# What happened to the Abilities pages?

Tags: support, privileges

What has happened to the

- https://stackoverflow.com/abilities
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/abilities

pages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were renamed to **privileges**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/privileges
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: Maybe a redirect is in order?